# How to change Android(java) App icon programmatically?

Tags: java, android, icons, android-manifest, shortcut

I have multiple icon buttons on my ChangeAppIcon Activity, When Clicked on any iconbutton it should change app icon.
To make my question more specific i want to do it like telegram where premium user can change there app icons.

I tried using activity-alias for and set its target activity as .Mainactivity, this worked but not upto the mark as on changing the icon 1st time it worked well but for 2nd time app is getting disappeared from recent Apps.

```
//this methid is called inside onclick of any button
   private void changeIcon(int iconResId) {
        if(previousicon == iconResId){
            return;
        }
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

        // Enable the new icon
        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(ChangeAppIcon.this, "com.waf.congratulationmessages.MainActivityAlias" + iconResId),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        // Disable all previously enabled icons
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            if (i != iconResId) {
                manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                        new ComponentName(ChangeAppIcon.this, "com.waf.congratulationmessages.MainActivityAlias" + i),
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            }
        }

        manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                new ComponentName(ChangeAppIcon.this, "com.waf.congratulationmessages.MainActivity"),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Toast.makeText(ChangeAppIcon.this, "Icon Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This is how i defined Manfiest for activity alias :

```
<activity-alias
            android:name=".MainActivityAlias4"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon4"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon4"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias
            android:name=".MainActivityAlias3"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon3"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon3"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
        <activity-alias
            android:name=".MainActivityAlias2"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon2"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
      ... //further same for MainActivityAlias1
```

please tell me is my code wrong or there is some another method to do so, As its not impossible because not only telegram but many other apps has this feature where user changes the app icon form the given list.